# Find all combinations of 3 elements from array of n elements

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I was thinking about the fastest possible algorithm to return all combinations of unique 3 elements from an array of n elements. The obvious one is the O(n^3) solution, which takes under consideration all possible combinations, but this is bruteforce, and I intend to find something much quicker. Looking for an answer in C++

Comment: If you really need 'all' combinations, it's impossible to make a solution faster than O(n^3) since the size of output is already O(n^3).

Comment: Sorry, i was thinking about unique solutions. Im gonna edit the question

Comment: unique solution means?

Comment: It means, that i am looking for combinations containing 3 elements, but without repetitions of same combinations. I treat combination unique if it differs from all others by at least one element ( in my problem it is index of an array's element)

Comment: See http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *worst* case (all the items of the array are different) you have

```
n ! / ((n - 3)! * 3!) == n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) / 6
```

distinct items to output and thus `O(n**3)` is all you can achieve.
If the array has many items, but few *distinct* ones, you can preprocess it:
remove all the item ocurrencies, but three:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1] -> [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

If you have a good hash function for the array's items the preprocess stage takes `O(N)`. In the *best* case (all the items are same) the prepocess takes `O(N)` 
and the only answer output is `O(1)` so you have `O(N)` for the entire
routine.

For the arbitrary array, you can't have complexity better than `O(N)` (since you have to scan the entire array). Finally, the complexity in case of preprocessing and good hash function for  the array's items is in the range of

```
 [O(N)..O(N**3)]
```

If you're lucky the process will be much quicker; if you have large data to output, well, you have but output the large collection...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. Because no matter what you do you need to get those 3 different elements. which has size `nC3 = n*(n-1)*(n-2)/6`. You need to iterate this any times for sure. So you will have `O(n^3)` complexity minimum.

Comment: Even if ( as mentioned in my question ) i look only for unique permutations? So that set of

Comment: SO that permutation [1 2 3 ] is the same as [3 2 1]